# How to manage the registration quota in Firebase authentication using Firebase Functions?

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin, quota

I am creating a user registration process through firebase functions.

I have read in the firebase console the following:

> To protect your project from any inappropriate use, we limit the number of records (both anonymous and those that use email and password) that can be made in your application from the same IP address. In this section you can request and schedule temporary changes for this fee.

I understand that the ip registered by the firebase authentication service is the ip of the server where the function is executed.

In this case, how is the registration quota controlled to prevent malicious use? Is there any way to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The quota described in that section mostly applies to calls coming from the client-side SDKs, like those from iOS and Android devices, and web pages. Since anyone with your configuration data (which is anyone who uses your app) can call these APIs, the quota protects against abuse from malicious users.

In Cloud Functions you're using the Admin SDK to create users, and the Admin SDK can only be used by someone who has the credentials for your project. For that reason, the code in Cloud Functions runs at a higher trust level and is not subject to these quota.

If you ever hit a Authentication quota issue in Cloud Functions code (or other code in a trusted environment that uses the Admin SDK), [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.